# Render conditional with long in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have this very simple column that needs to turn red if the value is below 15.

```
rendered="#{resultClub.noSeries lt 15 }"
```

But the noSeries is a Long/long which always return 0 or null to compare with. Is there a way to get around this problem?

```
<p:column id="hcp80200" sortBy="#{resClub.hcp80200}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Hcp 80% - 200</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText rendered="#{resultClub.noSeries gt 14 }" value="#{resClub.hcp80200}" />
                    <h:outputText rendered="#{resultClub.noSeries lt 15 }" value="#{resClub.hcp80200}" style="background-color: red;"/>

                </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rendered` is used whether to display a component or not. To conditionally style your JSF component, you have to use css classes. Lets say you want to style `outputText` component. Then you do it like this where style1 and style2 are css classes.

```
 <h:outputText styleClass="#{not empty resultClub.noSeries and resultClub.noSeries < 15  ? 'style1' : 'style2'}"/>.
```

So when the condition is true `style1` will be used otherwise `style2`.

Comment: No I want it rendered colored when below and normal with as shown in the answer below.

Comment: Do you know what the attribute `rendered` means in JSF? It means the component is either displayed or not. So if the expression evaluates to `true` then that component will be displayed if it is `false` nothing will be shown in the browser. What you need is to use two `css class` each shown based on the condition that you want. You don't need `rendered`.

Comment: So how would you choose style depending on values?

Comment: Lets say you want to style `outputText` component. Then you do it like this where `style1` and `style2` are css classes.

`<h:outputText styleClass="#{not empty resultClub.noSeries and resultClub.noSeries < 15  ? 'style1' : 'style2'}"/>`. So when the condition is true `style1` will be used otherwise `style2`.

Comment: Can you update your answer with that info so I can accept it?

Comment: Empty: The empty operator is a prefix operation that can be used to determine whether a value is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

The && will not work since it fails parsing. You can use "and" instead.

When comparing you can't use <. But "lt" for less than and "gt" will work just fine.

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{(resClub.noSeries == null) || (resClub.noSeries gt 14) }" value="#{resClub.hcp80200}" />
<h:outputText rendered="#{ (resClub.noSeries != null) and (resClub.noSeries lt 15) }" value="#{resClub.hcp80200}" style="background-color: red;"/>
```

Comment: You are right on both instances, by bad. You can use `&amp;&amp;` too for &&, but it's a bit ugly. In fact plain `&&` doesn't work because `&` is a special character in XML, you need to escape it. But `and` keyword is better for readability.